# Error: JSON.parse: expected ',' or ']' after array element

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs

Am newbie to `Json` am getting this error while call json my json file expected `',' or ']'`

```
[
{
    "modules":
        [
                {
                   "title":"name of module1",
                   "description":"description of module1",
                   "weeks":[{"id":1, "title":"Week 01"}]
                },

                {
                   "title":"name of module2",
                   "description":"description of module2",
                   "weeks":[{"id":2, "title":"Week 02"},{"id":3,"title":"Week 03"}]
                }
        ]
  },
{

    "products":
      [
        {
          "url":"http://dummyimage.com/242x200/f3f3f3/2d2d2d.png",
          "description":"Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.",
          "viewurl" : "/",
          "savebtn" : "save"
        },
        {
          "url":"http://dummyimage.com/242x200/f3f3f3/2d2d2d.png",
          "description":"Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.",
          "viewurl" : "/",
          "savebtn" : "save"
        }
      ]
}

]
```

hope i did correct i dont know what is happening its getting `Error: JSON.parse: expected ',' or ']' after array element`  am attempting to use in angular js controller

```
app.controller('settingsController', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('assets/javascripts/datas.json').then(function(result){
        $scope.employe = result.data;
        $scope.prod = result
    })
});
```

and in view

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="datas in prod.products">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img ng-src="{{ datas.url }}" alt="product">
                <div class="caption">
                   <h3>{{ datas.caption}} </h3>
                   <p>{{ datas.description}}</p>
                   <p><a role="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-href="{{datas.viewurl}}">Button</a> <a role="button" class="btn btn-default" href="#">{{datas.savebtn}}</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and the error in console

> Error: JSON.parse: expected ',' or ']' after array element at line 76 column 9 of the JSON data cc@/test/assets/javascripts/vendors/angular.js:14:289 Ud/this.defaults.transformResponse<@/test/assets/javascripts/vendors/angular.js:69:58 xc/<@/test/assets/javascripts/vendors/angular.js:68:352 r@/test/assets/javascripts/vendors/angular.js:7:288 xc@/test/assets/javascripts/vendors/angular.js:68:336 b@/test/assets/javascripts/vendors/angular.js:70:65 ye/e/l.promise.then/K@/test/assets/javascripts/vendors/angular.js:100:59 ye/f/<.then/<@/test/assets/javascripts/vendors/angular.js:101:235 Zd/this.$get

Comment: Hmm, http://JSONLint.com says it's all good. Can you show your code around where you're attempting to use `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Is there more to that error message like a stack trace?

Comment: @Phil yup added my error stack

Comment: Have you perhaps registered a response transformer with the `$httpProvider`? If so, what does it look like?

Comment: @phil yup using 'ngRoute'

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what *"using 'ngRoute'"* means. Also, is the JSON block at the top of your question the entire contents of `assets/javascripts/datas.json`? Check your browser's *Network* developer console and inspect the server response for that file to make sure it matches exactly

Comment: Using a JSON editor you could check over the response just to make sure it all matches as you expect... http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred for me when I parsed JSON from a string literal. When I copied in the JSON, I forgot that the escape sequences would need to be double escaped.

**Example of the problem:**

```
var data = JSON.parse('[{"key": "This value has \"a quoted\" string"}]');
```

While the string value is valid JSON, the escape sequences are lost. Then need to be double escaped:

**Corrected version:**

```
var data = JSON.parse('[{"key": "This value has \\\"a quoted\\\" string"}]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for me the problem occurs if I have a :// (e.g. http://) inside my json stirng for this reason I replaced it and it worked.